# Firefox address bar dropdown has no text (bug?)

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am not sure if this is a bug or some configuration has changed, but for some time (a couple of FF versions) now my Firefox Address bar drop-down has no text, just site fav-icons. I hope the screenshot will help.
Firefox version: 19.0.2

[image: Firefox address bar]

My question is - how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried switching to the default theme?

Comment: @gronostaj yes, just did it, restarted FF but no change...

Comment: Does clicking on the line actually take you to a page?

Comment: @ernie yes, that works. Actually I just had an idea - is it possible to start firefox with all plugins disabled? Kind of in safe mode...? Or would I have to manually disable all plugins / add-ons? I think it could help to check if some plugin messes this up...

Comment: Duh, found it under help... :) "Restart with Add-ons disabled". I knew I had seen it. So I did that and now the texts are there... Will now look for the bad add-in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gronostaj I came to the idea that some add-on might interfere here, and after restarting with add-ons disabled, and afterwards turning on one by one, I found that "Delicious Extension 2.3.1" was the one that disabled my address texts.
Now there is a newer official version of [Delicious Bookmarks](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/delicious-bookmarks) by Yahoo and it does not have this problem.